# What is Ethernet Adaptor (wc5)

Tags: macos, network, ethernet

In my Network Preferences panel, I've just noticed a network type I didn't see before.

The name is "Ethernet Adaptor (wc5)" (note it says Adaptor and not Adapter). It has an IP, it's yellow, and it says "Ethernet Adaptor (wc5) has a self-assigned IP address and will not be able to connect to the Internet."

What is it? Where does it come from? I am connected via WiFi - and, probably not a coincidence, I have internet issues right now (some sites work some don't).

What is happening?

EDIT: Disabled this network adapter, and now Internet flies. I don't know what it is and how it got there...

Comment: Did you ever plug something other than cable into your Ethernet plug.

Comment: Wirecast (wc5) from Telestream is a live video streaming production tool that allows Mac and Windows users to create live or on-demand broadcasts for the web......? Did you install it ?

Comment: Never heard of Wirecast or Telestream, however I have recently installed TeamViewer. Maybe related?

Comment: I have TeamViewer, and it does not set up that Ethernet Adaptor. You might inadvertently done something or plugged a for example USB to Ethernet or similar, that then installed that option. Just remove it from your Internet profiles.

Answer (score 1):

The (wc5) is probably from Wirecast. Do you have it installed?

It may have added an interface so it can stream and grabbed what it thought was an Ethernet interface but was actually your WiFi interface.

Comment: I have TeamViewer